# Which of my string indexing functions in Kotlin is semantically closer to my Java one?

Tags: java, comparative-review, kotlin

I have a working string indexing method in Java and did convert in Kotlin.

All methods shown below produce the same result but as I am really new to the Kotlin language I wanted to ask which of my two Kotlin implementations is semantically "more equal" to my Java code.

Here is my Java code where "copiedList" is an ArrayList:

```
public static Map<String, Integer> count(List<String> copiedList) {

        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (String string : copiedList) {
            String lowerString = string.toLowerCase();
            if (!map.containsKey(lowerString)) {
                map.put(lowerString, 1);
            } else {
                int integer = map.get(lowerString);
                map.put(lowerString, integer + 1);
            }
        }

        return map;
    }
```

My Kotlin implementation 1:

```
fun countWords(splittedArray: Array<String>): Map<String, Int> {
        return splittedArray.asSequence().filterNot { it.isBlank() }.map { it.toLowerCase() }. groupingBy { it }.eachCount()
}
```

or Kotlin implementation 2:

```
fun countWordsSeq(textSequence: Sequence<String>): Map<String, Int> {
        return textSequence.filterNot { it.isBlank() }.map { it.toLowerCase() }. groupingBy { it }.eachCount()
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Code Review Stack Exchange. The two different implementations you want us to compare here are *extremely* similar. The first one is basically doing `countWordsSeq(splittedArray.asSequence())` - that's pretty much all I can say.

Comment: Hello @SimonForsberg thanks for your answer. I know that both are extremely similar. My question is which is closer to the java implementation as Java uses List immediately and in the first Kotlin implementation has to convert it first to a "list".
Has that an impact on runtime?

Comment: 1) `.filterNot { it.isBlank() }` is not inside your java code, so the code examples are not equal! 2) Your implementation 1 is closer t0 your java code, because both do not evaluate lazily - which Sequence does. To achieve this, the java code must have used Streams.

Comment: If you actually want to compare Java and Kotlin in this scenario, better to compare Java 8 Stream implementation of this with Kotlin.